# Moving Windows 7 across drives, then installing Ubuntu for dual-boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, multi-boot

After trying out Ubuntu for a few days via Wubi, I want to take the next step and set it up on its own drive.

My system has two drives: a 320 GB drive which contains the OS, and a 1 TB drive which contains some programs and random files (mostly games). I've been looking at [this guide](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html), and the following is what I believe would be the correct procedure:

1. Use [GParted (probably the Live CD)](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php) to move and shrink the partition on the terabyte drive so that the drive has room enough to copy the 320 GB disk over at its beginning.
2. Copy the partition on the 320 GB drive to the start of the terabyte drive.
3. Disconnect the 320 gigabyte drive and make sure Windows boots from the terabyte drive. If needed, fix the drive letter assignments so that paths are correct again.
4. Reconnect the 320 gigabyte drive and disconnect the terabyte drive.
5. Install Ubuntu on the 320 gigabyte drive via the Live CD.
6. Reconnect the terabyte drive.

Does this sound good? Also, at this point should Grub detect windows on the other drive and offer me the option of which to boot when I power up the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. copy 320GB drive to 1TB drive
2. take out 320GB drive and see whether windows boots (you might have to connect the 1TB hard drive to the port that the 320GB drive used to be connected to)
3. in case windows does not boot -> do all fixes until windows boots from 1TB hard drive
4. reconnect 320GB drive, boot from 1TB drive, and delete 320GB drive.
5. now you have a clean 320GB drive and your 1TB drive with windows and your data
6. boot from ubuntu install cd (both drives connected!!)
7. install ubuntu onto 320GB drive. Ubuntu will then modify the boot loader on the 1TB disk, so that you can choose @ computer startup which operating system you want to use.

There are obviously alternative ways, but what you should NOT do is, to install ubuntu while the other hard drive is disconnected - unless you want to unplug hard drives in the future.